# PHP send mail with attachment AND html template

Tags: php, html, email

my question is simple...

I have coded the send HTML mail, and plains with attachment but what about HTML with attachments? my header has to be content-type:multipart/mixed; and that doesn't work for HTML messages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use something like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). it's trivial to send out dual html + plaintext emails with attachments and embedded images with either of them, and they're both free and easy to install/use.